# Sliding up panel with zoom image. Zoom not working

Tags: android, custom-controls, pinchzoom

I am using Sliding up panel (com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout), drawerlayout and zoomable image view in a layout. The problem is that when i disable sliding up panel zoom function starts working. But not otherwise. Any help would be great

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/itemlayout">


<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.shopistan.shopand.ZoomImage">

        <com.shopistan.shopand.ZoomableImageView
            android:id="@+id/IMAGEID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ff000000"
            android:id="@+id/layout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductName"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductPrice"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="In Stock"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/ProductSpecial"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/addcart"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="40dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/dragView">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/dragView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="MORE INFO"
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductName1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductPrice1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductPrice2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="In Stock"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/ProductSpecial1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Description"
                android:id="@+id/Desc"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/desccon"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Care Instructions"
                android:id="@+id/care"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/carecon"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawercheck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="My Cart"
        android:id="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:textColor="#d71920"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d6d6d6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="PRODUCT"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprof"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderqty"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprice"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="PRICE(PKR)"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprice"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d6d6d6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/checkout_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#ff000000"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:listSelector="#ff000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="TOTAL (Before Shipping):"
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="PKR 0"
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHECKOUT"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#d71920"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by placing the content of main screen i.e zoomable image inside framelayout of sliding up panel. here is the working code.!!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/itemlayout">


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shopistan.shopand.Prodpage" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="50dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/dragView">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context="com.shopistan.shopand.Prodpage">

                    <com.shopistan.shopand.TouchImageView
                        android:id="@+id/IMAGEID"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    <!--<com.shopistan.shopand.ZoomableImageView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/IMAGEID1"-->
                    <!--android:adjustViewBounds="true"-->

                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->
                    <!--<com.shopistan.shopand.ZoomableImageView-->
                    <!--android:id="@+id/IMAGEID2"-->
                    <!--android:adjustViewBounds="true"-->

                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->


                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:background="#ff000000"
                        android:id="@+id/layout">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Medium Text"
                            android:id="@+id/ProductName"

                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffff0000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Small Text"
                            android:id="@+id/ProductPrice"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="In Stock"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:id="@+id/ProductSpecial"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewcart"
                        android:src="@drawable/addcart"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
                        android:clickable="true" />


                </RelativeLayout>


            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/dragView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="MORE INFO"
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductName1"

                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/ProductPrice1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/ProductPrice2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="In Stock"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/ProductSpecial1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Description"
                android:id="@+id/Desc"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/desccon"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Care Instructions"
                android:id="@+id/care"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffff0000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/carecon"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:textColor="#ffbdbdbd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawercheck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="My Cart"
        android:id="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:textColor="#d71920"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d6d6d6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutnavheadertext"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="PRODUCT"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprof"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderqty"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprice"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="PRICE(PKR)"
            android:id="@+id/checkoutnavesubheaderprice"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#d6d6d6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/checkout_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#ff000000"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:listSelector="#ff000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerchecksubheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/total"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="TOTAL (Before Shipping):"
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="PKR 0"
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffffffff"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHECKOUT"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#d71920"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```